# Upload the source change to the PPA on Launchpad

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system, debian, launchpad

I downloaded hello package from debian archive. After adding testing.sh and postinst to that folder, I ran: sudo apt-get source --compile hello
It created deb files and changes file.

I also created PPA launchpad as below:
git remote add launchpad [https://launchpad.net/~hectorta/+archive/ubuntu/hello-ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ehectorta/+archive/ubuntu/hello-ppa)
git push launchpad main

In /etc/dput.cf, I edited:

```
[ppa] 
fqdn                = ppa.launchpad.net
method              = ftp
# replace <launchpad-id> with your Launchpad ID
incoming            = ~hectorta/ubuntu/hello-ppa
login               =anonymous
allow_unsigned_uploads  = 0
```

Then in hello folder, I ran:
dput ppa:hectorta/hello-ppa ../hello_2.10-2_amd64.changes
It has error: No host ppa:... found in config
Then I tried: dput ppa ../hello_2.10-2_amd64.changes
It has error: gpgme_op_verify: GPGME: No data

As I know, command: dput ppa:hectorta/hello-ppa ../hello_2.10-2_amd64.changes
should be correct. Please tell me how to solve this issue to upload it to launchpad.